# Get the inserted row causing the execution of the trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to get the value of the row causing the execution of the trigger. So I can pass it (*as a parameter*) to a stored procedure.

The stored procedure accepts as input a table type which is defined in the script below:

```
CREATE TYPE PersonTableType AS TABLE
(
    Id int primary key,
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50)
)
```

The procedure *(insert in the ArchivePerson table the inserted row from the trigger)*

```
Create PROCEDURE sp1
@PersonType PersonTableType Readonly

As
BEGIN
    Insert Into ArchivePerson 
    Select * From @PersonType
END
```

How do I declare my trigger?
I tried something like:

```
Alter TRIGGER insertPerson 
   ON  Person 
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @PersonType PersonTableType;

    ??

    Exec sp1 @PersonType

END
```

Comment: If you read the docs for building a trigger for SQL Server you will come across the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) is very good. Also right from the start you need to keep in mind, and handle, the fact that a trigger could run on 0-N rows i.e. it might fire when none are modified and it might fire when 10,000 (or any other value of N) are modified.

Comment: So calling an SP you might have to do in a RBAR fashion, which is really not ideal for a database. You might want to consider other options.

Comment: Same thing for the parameter of my procedure, it can run on 0-N rows as long as the type is @PersonType .

Comment: @BoufarTarek A table variable is just a special table. You will need to populate it with the appropriate rows before you execute your procedure and pass the table variable as a parameter. To do that, you simple insert the rows that you want to pass to the procedure - typically by selecting from the inserted and deleted pseudo tables. But please reconsider the use of a stored procedure. The procedure you posted is trivial (and has bad coding habits) and you gain nothing obvious by attempting to use it in your trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inserted` table has the rows which were, well, inserted. It has the same columns with your original [Person] table, so use the appropriate columns:

```
Alter TRIGGER insertPerson 
   ON  Person 
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @PersonType PersonTableType;

    insert @PersonType(Id,FirstName,LastName)
        select <corresponding columns>
        from inserted

    Exec sp1 @PersonType

END
```